# MySQL OUTFILE query complains that "file already exists" but the file does not exist at all

Tags: mysql, linux

I am writing a very simple shell script to dump a table into CSV file. Here is part of it:

```
day=`/bin/date +'%Y-%m-%d'`
file="/tmp/table-$day.csv"
rm $file
query="SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE '$file' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"
echo "$query" | mysql <connection_parameters>
```

I put in `rm $file` to make sure that the file does not exist prior to the query's execution.

However, when I execute the script, I get conflicting messages:

```
rm: cannot remove `/tmp/table-2013-02-08.csv': No such file or directory
ERROR 1086 (HY000) at line 1: File '/tmp/table-2013-02-08.csv' already exists
```

I cannot find the OUTFILE anywhere in the machine.

So what is wrong.. ?

Thank you.

Comment: Does /tmp exist?  Do you have write access to it?  I wonder if MySQL is trying to write to /mysql/tmp/ instead of relative to where you're executing the shell script.

Comment: thanks Jacob. /tmp exists and is writable. Manually executing the query runs successfully.

Comment: I noticed that manually executing the query succeeds the first time, but not the second time...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the answer.

OUTFILE creates the file on the MySQL server, rather than on my MySQL client's machine.

Comment: +1.  In retrospect, that is obvious since the query runs at the server  ... but I did not see it.  I was looking at the original question and thinking you somehow had a permissions problem or something.  It made me smile to see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have this in /etc/passwd

mysql:x:27:27:MariaDB Server:/var/lib/mysql:/sbin/nologin

change shell to /bin/bash instead